# Change color selector/text new Text MaterialButton

Tags: android, material-components

I need to customize the text color or background color of the selector when button is selected, because the color of the text its too similar and the text disappears

This is my code:

```
  <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
            android:text="@string/lbl_forgotten_password"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_text_1"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using `selector`.

Create a new xml file into the drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/text_color" android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg"/>
    <item android:color="@color/text_normal" />
</selector>
```

After

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/your_xml_file_name"
        android:text="@string/lbl_forgotten_password"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: android@background does not work on material buttons. use tbackgroundTInt or stroke/strokeWidth to manipulate the background of a material button